# move select box a bit lower (to align to text before it) in html

Tags: html, css

I have a HTML5 page.
The selection box is not aligned to the text ( "Select Discipline") before it.

How could I lower the selection box a little bit to align the center of the selection box to the text before it?

```html
        <div class="row">
        <div class="px-3">
            <div class="d-sm-flex align-items-xl-stretch justify-content-between mb-4">
                <h1 class="h4 mb-0 text-gray-800">&nbsp;&nbsp;Select Discipline:&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;</h1>
                <div id="discipline_div">
                    <select name="discipline" id="discipline">
                        <option value="All Disciplines" selected disabled hidden>--Select--</option>
                        <option value="All Disciplines" name="discipline_name_all">All Disciplines</option>
                        {% for discipline in query_results %}
                        <option value="{{ discipline.name }}" name="discipline_name">{{ discipline.name }}</option>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </select>&emsp;
                    <button class="button4" type="button" onclick="delete_button_clicked()" id="delete_button">&#x2716;</button></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<button class="button3" type="button" id="add_more">Add Discipline</button><p>


<script>

$('#add_more').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    ++current_id;
    $("p").before("           &emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;<div class='field' id="+ current_id + ">         <select name=" + current_id +  ">\n" +
        "                        <option value=\"All Disciplines\" selected disabled hidden>--Select--</option>\n" +
        "                        <option value=\"All Disciplines\" name=\"discipline_name_all2\">All Disciplines</option>\n" +
        "                        {% for discipline in query_results %}\n" +
        "                        <option value=\"{{ discipline.name }}\" name=\"discipline_name2\">{{ discipline.name }}</option>\n" +
        "                        {% endfor %}\n" +
        "                    </select>&ensp;&nbsp;\n" +
        "                    <button class=\"button4\" type=\"button\" onclick=\"delete_button_clicked2(this.id)\" id="+ current_id + ">&#x2716;</button></div><br><br>&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;");

    console.log(current_id);
});

</script>
```

I want to make all the lines have same space, however, now the space between first and 2rn line is bigger than others, so I want to lower the selection box in first line.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/upyTQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like this?

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="px-3">
    <div class="d-sm-flex align-items-xl-stretch justify-content-between mb-4">

      <div id="discipline_div">
        <span class="h4 mb-0 text-gray-800">&nbsp;&nbsp;Select Discipline:     </span>
        <select name="discipline" id="discipline">
          <option value="All Disciplines" selected="" disabled="" hidden="">--Select--</option>
          <option value="All Disciplines" name="discipline_name_all">All Disciplines</option>
          {% for discipline in query_results %}
            <option value="{{ discipline.name }}" name="discipline_name">{{ discipline.name }}</option>
          {% endfor %}
        </select>
        <button 
          class="button4" 
          type="button" 
          onclick="delete_button_clicked()" 
          id="delete_button"
        >✖</button>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the line-height attribute:

```
            <div class="row">
                            <div class="px-3">
                                <div class="d-sm-flex align-items-xl-stretch justify-content-between mb-4">
                                    
                                    <div id="discipline_div">
                                        <span class="h4 mb-0 text-gray-800" style="
                line-height: 2.2;
            ">&nbsp;&nbsp;Select Discipline:     </span><select name="discipline" id="discipline">
                                            <option value="All Disciplines" selected="" disabled="" hidden="">--Select--</option>
                                            <option value="All Disciplines" name="discipline_name_all">All Disciplines</option>
                                            {% for discipline in query_results %}
                                            <option value="{{ discipline.name }}" name="discipline_name">{{ discipline.name }}</option>
                                            {% endfor %}
                                        </select> 
                                        <button class="button4" type="button" onclick="delete_button_clicked()" id="delete_button">✖</button></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```